# Setupluncher error: Failed to find main class in: plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.200.v20210416-2027

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install an engineering program, but whenever I run setup.exe I'm faced with the following  error:

```
Faild to find a main class in:C:\Users\Dr Malaeke\AppData\Local\Temp\comsolsetup.11488\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.200.v20210416-2027
```

I updated my JDK and I defined path for it (The last version is deleted), which didn't work.

Note : I don't have eclipse on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I had "User Variable" TEMP and TMP set to %userprofile%/AppData/Temp, and %userprofile% is my name, with a " " (space) in it...

When I deleted TEMP and TMP from my "User Variables" Windows 11 reverted to my "Environment Variables" TEMP and TMP (C:\WINDOWS\TEMP) and the installation proceeded further...

And after I set my user TEMP=C:\TEMP it worked perfectly... again... like before someone came up with the idea of setting a %userprofile% with space in it.

[image: Without TEMP = %userprofile%\AppData\Temp]